# How to compare two counts related by a supertable?

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql and I have 4 tables involved in a query.

The relevant fields are the idRide from table ride, idDriver from table driver, idOwner from table owner and idDependant from dependant.

Driver is a supertable where both owners and dependants are drivers, in the table ride, you get idDriver and you can check on the tables owners and dependants to see which driver they correspond to. Each dependant also has as a foreign key the id of the owner they depend on.

How do I count the rides of owners and dependants and then I show only the owners who have more rides than their dependants?

I tried the following query but it does not work:

```
SELECT r.idDriver, ow.idOwner, idDependant,
SUM(CASE WHEN r.idDriver = ow.idOwner THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OwnerRides,
SUM(CASE WHEN r.idDriver = idDependant THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DepRides
FROM owners AS ow
INNER JOIN dependants AS dp
ON ow.idOwner = dp.idOwner 
INNER JOIN ride AS r
ON OwnerRides > DepRides
GROUP BY ow.idOwner;
```

I also tried using a subquery (a select as a field of another select) but it can only return one column and I need two columns (the id of the driver doing the ride and the count of rides).

Comment: The `ow` alias is not defined anywhere in the query. Are you sure this query even runs?

Comment: Woops, I translated the query fields' names from Portuguese to English to facilitate the question, forgot to replace the dn there. It should be owners AS ow. The query does run when I don't add the condition "ON OwnerRides > DepRides", otherwise it tells me it doesn't know the column "OwnerRides". I corrected the alias command now.

Comment: You have a strange (to me) table set up.  Driver should have its own id and rider.idDriver should link to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work for you:

```
select owners.idOwner, count(*) as OwnerRides, c.DependantRides from ride 
inner join owners on ride.idDriver = owners.idOwner
left join (select dependants.idDependant, dependants.idOwner, count(*) as DependantRides from ride 
inner join dependants on ride.idDriver = dependants.idDependant
group by dependants.idDependant, dependants.idOwner)c on owners.idOwner = c.idOwner
group by idOwner
having OwnerRides > DependantRides
```

[SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f5242/14)

Comment: Like Jão said
that solved the problem Kevin ,ty dude. unfortunately our teacher was unable to help since he was deported from the country where he lived. pray for him, stay safe.